# How do I mute certain tabs in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, audio

In Google Chrome, can I mute sound in a single tab? Suppose a tab has a youtube video that I would like to silence. However, I still want to hear the audio from another tab.

Comment: Related article 'Google explains why it won't add mute tab option': http://thenextweb.com/google/2014/02/11/google-explains-wont-add-mute-tab-option-chrome-considers-tab-audio-api-extensions/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an extension for that (sort of): https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nmkbaaijgpppbokgnhhoakihofedkgcc

it's okay in that it works most of the time. however chrome still uses a shared instance of flash (for example) in order to run faster, but it makes it very difficult to stop one part of that shared instance. IE (ugh) opens a new instance per tab, and you can mute individual tabs. you can give this a spin, but as far as I know it's as good as you'll get.

Comment: Thanks! Just curious, how do you mute a tab in IE (yes, ugh)?

Comment: if you open the native audio panel in windows, each tab in IE (9 at least) has it's own audio profile in the Mixer.

you can also mute all of the tabs by first selecting IE and pressing alt+F4 and getting chrome. (happy IE6 is almost dead day!)

Answer (score 5):

*From [lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/enable-chromes-mute-this-tab-shortcut-in-the-dev-chan-1640772471)...*

Get the [Dev Channel](http://lifehacker.com/5798237/which-channel-of-chrome-or-firefox-should-i-use) (if you're not already on it) and set the following flag:

```
chrome://flags/#enable-tab-audio-muting
```

Restart Chrome.

Comment: Indeed, simple and much more effective.