# No sounds played in google chrome tabs

Tags: google-chrome, audio, google-chrome-extensions, mute

I have somehow muted all the tabs in my google chrome. 
Youtube and other flash players are playing video, but there is no sound.

In Window 7 Volume mixer I can see Google chrome icon and it has muted icon there. But clicking that icon unmute sounds just for a second and then it's muted back on.

Seems that chrome itself or some of it extensions are turning mute...

Update: [How do I mute certain tabs in Chrome?](https://superuser.com/questions/374695/how-do-i-mute-certain-tabs-in-chrome) question seems related, but I don't have MuteTab extension installed in Chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK. I've found out what it was. I have [Chrome toolbox](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-toolbox-by-google/fjccknnhdnkbanjilpjddjhmkghmachn) extension installed and it has "Mute all tabs" functionality. And a keyboard shortcut for it is Alt+W. So I somehow pressed this combo and switched it on.